# Checksum Generator using ASLR

Tags: aslr

I'm a newbie here. I wanna match the PID in Windows Task Manager with the checksum/hash value generated by dynamic base ASLR in Visual Studio 2010? I have already enabled the ASLR in Visual Studio 2010 but no data is received. Any idea how?

Clues:

1. Windows functions `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`
2. `MODULEENTRY32`
3. Windows function `OpenProcess`

Appreciate it very much guys.

Giggsey